# Setting up hubot on an openfire server

Tags: openfire, hubot

I'm running Ubuntu and I am trying to get a [hubot](http://hubot.github.com/) to connect to my local openfire server.  I followed the tutorial [here](http://server.dzone.com/articles/installing-and-running-hubot), and everything went pretty smooth till toward the end, after editing the dependencies, I run `npm install` and receive two warnings:

```
npm WARN package.json node-xmpp@0.3.2 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field

> node-stringprep@0.1.11 install /opt/hubot/my-bot/node_modules/node-stringprep
> node-gyp rebuild
```

I'm not sure what it means that the repositories arn't supported and I tried `npm install node-stringprep` and a `node-gyp rebuild`.  The npm install gives me the same warnings, but finishes succesfully, while the rebuild gives me this error output:

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@0.12.1
gyp info using node@0.10.23 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn python
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/opt/hubot/my-bot/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/jake/.node-gyp/0.10.23/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/jake/.node-gyp/0.10.23',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/hubot/my-bot',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /opt/hubot/my-bot)
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:337:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-34-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /opt/hubot/my-bot
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.23
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Since they are warnings and not errors(on the npm install), I went ahead and started hubot to see if it would connect but it doesn't.  I don't get any errors from it but it doesn't connect.  The output when I run the bot:

```
jake@jake-Lenovo-G580:/opt/hubot/my-bot$ ./bin/hubot --adapter xmpp
npm WARN package.json node-xmpp@0.3.2 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field

> node-stringprep@0.1.11 install /opt/hubot/my-bot/node_modules/node-stringprep
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/opt/hubot/my-bot/node_modules/node-stringprep/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_stringprep/node-stringprep.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/node_stringprep.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/node_stringprep.node: Finished
  COPY Release/node_stringprep.node
make: Leaving directory `/opt/hubot/my-bot/node_modules/node-stringprep/build'
[Mon Dec 30 2013 13:39:23 GMT-0700 (MST)] INFO { username: 'hubot',
  password: 'asdf',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: '9090',
  rooms: [ { jid: 'hubot-test', password: false } ],
  keepaliveInterval: 30000 }
```

And nothing happens.

I double checked all the hubot xmpp fields several times to make sure they are correct, and although this particular output does not have it, I tried several variations of usernames -> `hubot@jake-lenovo-g580` and `hubot@jake-Lenovo-G580`, so that it matches my domain.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Any chance you were able to solve this?

Comment: I did, if you're still having problems let me know and I'll type up an answer tonight after work.

Comment: @JakeSellers, please don't leave a question unanswered if you know a solution.